# 'Error, expected expression int' and need some advice on structuring my c app

Tags: c

Hey guys I am currently working on a burger ordering system for a university assessment. The app basically stores a list of 25 orders (that is the maximum number of orders) each order can have unlimited burgers. I am getting an error (with the code I have attempted below)

```
40:13: error: expected expression int orderNumber = 0;
```

I have no idea what the problem is happening, could someone help please. Also before anyone points it out, I have not yet added something to verify if the memory allocation is valid (that is still a work in progress). Finally, I know this is not a straightforward question but any feedback would be nice. Here is the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {EMPTY, ACTIVE} status;
typedef enum {A, B, C, M} burgerPart;


struct burger
{
    int quantity;
    char burgerTitle[1000];
    burgerPart burgerType;
    float burgerPrice;
    float quantityBurgerPrice;
}burger;

struct order 
{
    int receiptNumber;
    int burgersize;
    struct burger * burgerItem;
    float totalPrice;
    status statusItem;
}order;

// My actual code has various functions here, but not relevant to error

int main(){

    struct order orderItem[24];
    int choice; 
    printf("Welcome to Tasty Burgers\n");

    do
    {
        choice = 1;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            int orderNumber = 0;

            orderNumber = getNumber(orderItem);


            printf("How many burgers would you like to order?\n");
            scanf(" %d", &orderItem[orderNumber].burgersize);
            int p;
            for (p = 0; p < orderItem[orderNumber].burgersize; p++) {
                orderItem[orderNumber].burgerItem = (struct burger *)calloc(orderItem[orderNumber].burgersize,(sizeof(burger)*orderNumber));

                printf("Please order burger %d\n", (p+1));
                printf("Select the Burger Type\nA – Chicken Burger – 15$\nB – Ham Burger – 17$\nC – Vegie Burger – 13$\nM - To return to main menu\n");
                char foodchoice[1000];
                fflush(stdin);
                fgets(foodchoice, 1000, stdin);
                fflush(stdin);

                if (strcmp(foodchoice, "A")==0)
                {
                    orderItem[orderNumber].burgerItem[p].burgerType = A;
                } else if (strcmp(foodchoice, "B")==0) {
                    orderItem[orderNumber].burgerItem[p].burgerType = B;
                } else if (strcmp(foodchoice, "C")==0) {
                    orderItem[orderNumber].burgerItem[p].burgerType = C;
                } else if (strcmp(foodchoice, "M")==0) {
                    orderItem[orderNumber].burgerItem[p].burgerType = M;  
                }

                if (orderItem[orderNumber].burgerItem[p].burgerType == M)
                {
                    continue;
                }


                //getProductPrice(orderItem, orderNumber, p);
                //quantitySelect(orderItem, orderNumber, p);    
                //calculateTotalPrice(orderItem, orderNumber, p); 
            }
          // printCurrentOrder(orderItem, orderNumber);



            break;

        case 2:

            break;


        case 3:

            break;

        case 4:

            break;



        default:
            break;
        }



    } while (choice != 4);


}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.,

Comment: I am using GCC on my Mac. Anyway, that fixes the issue (your comment is same as the answer below but thank you anyway)

Comment: I edited the original post to only focus on the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch`-statements do not allow to define variables right after a `case`; you can *define* `orderNumber` outside and just *assign* at any place then:

```
int orderNumber;
switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:     
        orderNumber = getNumber(orderItem);

...
```

Comment: Ahh alright. Thank you for the help fixes the problem.